# Select rows by comparing time column in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, unix-timestamp

I have a table in `MySQL` database which contains login time data (in Unix time/Epoch time format):

```
login_id    sign_in_time    sign_in_time_seconds    user_id
1           1406800000      5                       1
2           1406800100      0                       1
3           1406800350      10                      1
4           1406805426      0                       145
5           1406805504      0                       167
6           1406805503      30                      183
```

I need to select all rows where the same `user_id` has sign in more than one time within 2 minutes. It should only return the suspicious rows, not the earliest and valid login.

I have tried the following code but it doesn't seem to work:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM logintable t1 JOIN logintable t2 ON t1.login_id = t2.login_id
WHERE
  t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND
  (ABS((t1.sign_in_time+t1.sign_in_time_seconds)-(t2.sign_in_time+t2.sign_in_time_seconds) <= 120)
ORDER BY
  t1.user_id ASC;
```

The query should also only show the suspicious signed ins. According to the list on the top, it should return the following rows:

```
login_id    sign_in_time    sign_in_time_seconds    user_id
    2           1406800100      0                       1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is here:

```
ON t1.login_id = t2.login_id
```

This should be

```
ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
```

for it is the same *user* you want to compare login times for.

You can simply delete your ON clause and make your WHERE clause your new ON clause :-)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the condition on the login id.  However, I don't think the time comparison will get all the rows:  the time comparisons are only on the end of the login time not on the beginning.

Also, I think `exists` better conveys the intention of the query.  This will also prevent duplicates when there are multiple signin attempts within two minutes:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM logintable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM logintable t2 
              WHERE t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND
                    (t1.sign_in_time between t2.sign_in_time and t2.sign_in_time + t2.sign_in_time_seconds + 120 or
                     t2.sign_in_time between t1.sign_in_time and t1.sign_in_time + t1.sign_in_time_seconds + 120
                    )
             )
ORDER BY t1.user_id ASC;
```